# Getting first and last rows of dataframe groups based on values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a','a','a', 'b','b','a','a'],
                    'c2':[1,3,5,7,9,11,13],
                    'c3':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14]})



  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
1  a   3   4
2  a   5   6
3  b   7   8
4  b   9  10
5  a  11  12
6  a  13  14
```

I want to get the first and last rows every time the value in column c1 changes.

In the example, the output would be

```
  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
2  a   5   6
3  b   7   8
4  b   9  10
5  a  11  12
6  a  13  14
```

I can use

```
idx = np.where(df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()) != 0)[0]
```

to get the first rows like this

```
df.iloc[idx,:]

  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
3  b   7   8
5  a  11  12
```

but am unable to get the last rows

```
  c1  c2  c3
2  a   5   6
4  b   9  10
6  a  13  14
```

What would be the best way to get these rows?

Comment: Use `idx = np.where(df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift(-1)) != 0)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your solution with filtering by boolean masks:

```
df1 = df[df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift())]
print (df1)
  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
3  b   7   8
5  a  11  12

df2 = df[df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift(-1))]
print (df2)
  c1  c2  c3
2  a   5   6
4  b   9  10
6  a  13  14
```

And for all rows chain conditions by `|` for `bitwise OR`:

```
df3 = df[df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()) | df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift(-1))]
print (df3)
  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
2  a   5   6
3  b   7   8
4  b   9  10
5  a  11  12
6  a  13  14
```

Performance:

Obviously not groupby solution are faster, but best test in real data:

```
#7k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [53]: %timeit df.groupby(df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).nth([0, -1])
3.57 ms ± 283 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [54]: %timeit df[df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()) | df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift(-1))]
1.53 ms ± 6.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: `df[df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift(-1))]` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two operations, `groupby` + `nth` allows you to get the first and last rows in a single step.

```
df.groupby(df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).nth([0, -1])
```

```
  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
2  a   5   6
3  b   7   8
4  b   9  10
5  a  11  12
6  a  13  14
```